# What is the best way to load two text files into one TMemo component in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Let's say I have two text files (.txt) and I have a form with one TMemo Component on it. What would be the best way to quickly load both text files into the same Memo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `TStringList` to load each file and then use the [`AddStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.AddStrings) method to transfer the contents to the memo.

```
var
  Tmp: TStringList;
...
Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
try
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Tmp := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Tmp.LoadFromFile(FileName1);
    Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(Tmp);

    Tmp.LoadFromFile(FileName2);
    Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(Tmp);
  finally
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
finally
  Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
end;
```

In fact, this can easily be generalised to a potentially useful method like this:

```
procedure AppendMultipleTextFiles(Dest: TStrings; const FileNames: array of string);
var
  FileName: string;
  Tmp: TStringList;
begin
  Dest.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Tmp := TStringList.Create;
    try
      for FileName in FileNames do
      begin
        Tmp.LoadFromFile(FileName);
        Dest.AddStrings(Tmp);
      end;
    finally
      Tmp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Dest.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

You could then use the method like so:

```
Memo1.Lines.Clear;
AppendMultipleTextFiles(Memo1.Lines, [FileName1, FileName2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
sl := TstringList.Create;
try
  sl.LoadFromFile('1.TXT');
  memo1.Lines.Add(sl.Text);

  sl.Clear;
  sl.LoadFromFile('2.TXT');
  memo1.Lines.Add(s2.Text);


finally
  sl.Free
end;
```

Comment: Rather than using Text you can avoid creating that intermediate string, which could be very large, by using AddStrings. There is no need to clear sl before calling LoadFromFile. But the memo may need to be cleared.

Comment: Furthermore, the end result is a memo that contains two string, which themselves may contain linefeeds.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, *"the end result is a memo that contains two string, which themselves may contain linefeeds"* - Are you sure about this? I think you might be wrong.

Comment: @kobik I am quite sure. `TStrings.Add` increases `Count` by `1`. Do you really believe otherwise?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Try: `Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('1'#13#10'2');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('3'#13#10'4');` -> `Memo1.Lines.Count` is 4. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: @kobik OK, that's probably the case for the VCL `TMemo` which wraps the Win32 edit control. Not the case for `TStringList` and not likely the case for FMX. I had not contemplated the storage behind a VCL `TMemo`, sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, You are correct about `TStringList`. interesting, I didn't even knew it could hold a single line containing linefeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Without any TStringList:

```
uses System.IOUtils;

Memo1.Text := TFile.ReadAllText('1.txt') + #13#10 + TFile.ReadAllText('2.txt');
```

When you assign string with line breaks to TStrings.Text, this string will be automatically splitted into multiple strings, what can be proven with a following console program:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.IOUtils;

var StringList: TStringList;
    s: string;
begin
  try
    StringList := TStringList.Create;
    StringList.Text := TFile.ReadAllText('1.txt');
    for s in StringList do
      begin
        Writeln(s);
        Writeln('-----');
      end;
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

More from [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Text)

> When setting Text, the value will be parsed by separating into substrings whenever a carriage return or linefeed is encountered. (The two do not need to form pairs).

This method improves readability, but consumes big amount of memory.

Comment: I see the same problem as in the @Ago answer, but I think, it's the shortest method: one line pro file :)